# Code Review: Generating Worst Case for QuickSort Middle Pivot

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I've implemented a solution aiming to generate the worst-case scenario for QuickSort using the middle pivot strategy in Java. My goal is to rearrange an input array to produce the worst performance during sorting.

Here's the code I've written:

```
public class WorstCaseForMiddlePivotQuickSort<E extends Comparable<? super E>> {
    private static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> int partition(List<E> arr, int low, int high) {
        int middlePivotIndex = (low + high) / 2;
        E pivot = arr.get(middlePivotIndex);
        
        int i = low;
        int j = high;
        
        while (i <= j) {
            while (arr.get(i).compareTo(pivot) < 0) {
                i++;
            }
            while (arr.get(j).compareTo(pivot) > 0) {
                j--;
            }
            
            if (i <= j) {
                Collections.swap(arr, i, j);
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        
        return i;
    }
    
    
    private static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> void quickSortUsingMiddlePivot(List<E> arr, int low, int high, List<Integer> partitionIndexHistory) {
        if (low >= high) {
            return;
        }
        int partitionIndex = partition(arr, low, high);
        partitionIndexHistory.add(partitionIndex);
        quickSortUsingMiddlePivot(arr, low, partitionIndex - 1, partitionIndexHistory);
        quickSortUsingMiddlePivot(arr, partitionIndex + 1, high, partitionIndexHistory);
    }
    
    public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> List<E> generateWorstCaseForQuickSortPivotPoint(List<E> input, Map<Integer, Integer> currentIndexToPreviousIndexMapping) {
        List<E> reverseOrdered = new ArrayList<>(input);
        reverseOrdered.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());
        List<E> worstCase = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(reverseOrdered.size(), null));
        int inOrderCount = 0;
        while (inOrderCount < worstCase.size()) {
            int whereToPut = (reverseOrdered.size() - inOrderCount - 1) / 2;
            if (worstCase.get(whereToPut) != null) {
                whereToPut = retrieveIndex(whereToPut, currentIndexToPreviousIndexMapping);
            }
            worstCase.set(whereToPut, reverseOrdered.get(inOrderCount));
            currentIndexToPreviousIndexMapping.put(whereToPut, worstCase.size() - inOrderCount - 1);
            inOrderCount++;
        }
        return worstCase;
    }
    
    public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> void quickSortUsingMiddlePivot(List<E> input, List<Integer> partitionIndexHistory) {
        if (input == null || input.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        quickSortUsingMiddlePivot(input, 0, input.size() - 1, partitionIndexHistory);
    }
    
    private static int retrieveIndex(int currentIndex, Map<Integer, Integer> currentIndexToPreviousIndexMapping) {
        if (!currentIndexToPreviousIndexMapping.containsKey(currentIndex)) {
            return currentIndex;
        }
        return retrieveIndex(currentIndexToPreviousIndexMapping.get(currentIndex), currentIndexToPreviousIndexMapping);
    }
}
```

Here is my very simple test. Although my simple test has passed, I'm still concerned about the accuracy of my approach.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.*;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static worstcasegenerator.WorstCaseForMiddlePivotQuickSort.generateWorstCaseForQuickSortPivotPoint;
import static worstcasegenerator.WorstCaseForMiddlePivotQuickSort.quickSortUsingMiddlePivot;

class WorstCaseForMiddlePivotQuickSortTest {
    
    private List<Integer> generatePrefixSizeList(int size) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        return list;
    }
    
    private void checkIfIsWorstCase(List<Integer> partitionIndexHistory, int size) {
        assertEquals(size - 1, partitionIndexHistory.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < partitionIndexHistory.size(); i++) {
            assertEquals(size - 1 - i, partitionIndexHistory.get(i));
        }
    }
    
    @Test
    void testWorstCaseForMiddlePivotQuickSortGenerator() {
        for (int size = 1; size <= 100; size++) {
            List<Integer> testInput = generatePrefixSizeList(size);
            List<Integer> partitionIndexHistory = new ArrayList<>();
            Map<Integer, Integer> currentIndexToPreviousIndexMapping = new HashMap<>();
            List<Integer> worstCase = generateWorstCaseForQuickSortPivotPoint(testInput, currentIndexToPreviousIndexMapping);
            System.out.println("input size: " + size + " , worst case input : " + worstCase);
            quickSortUsingMiddlePivot(worstCase, partitionIndexHistory);
            System.out.println("partition index history: " + partitionIndexHistory);
            checkIfIsWorstCase(partitionIndexHistory, size);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm seeking feedback on the correctness and potential improvements for this solution. I'm particularly interested in optimizing the algorithm, enhancing code readability, and ensuring the logic for index management is effective.

Any feedback, suggestions, or improvements would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: By the way the stackexchange network has this site for reviews: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @harold Oh, thank you! I wasn't aware that such a code review site even existed!

Comment: I'm curious *why* you would want a worst-case Quicksort algorithm.  Is there a reason?

Comment: Tooting my own horn: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/226467/quicksort-with-insertion-sort-and-improved-pivot-selection

Comment: @markspace I know people don't mess up the input when they know the pivot strategy in real life. I'm just doing this for fun, not for any serious reasons.

Comment: In that case, "just for fun", implement something similar to the middle of three pivot selection, except instead of picking the middle value, pick the least or the greatest (just consistently pick one of those).

Comment: @markspace Thanks for all the suggestions! Implementing a more comprehensive worst-case scenario generator sounds like a great idea. I'll focus on developing that approach later on.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I've implemented a solution aiming to generate the worst-case scenario for QuickSort using the middle pivot strategy in Java. ..."*

For reference, here is a ported version of the, *"[Hoare partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme)"* algorithm, from *Wikipedia*.
This scheme uses a *middle-point* pivot.

I haven't added any comments; those are the originals.

```java
class Quicksort {
    // Sorts a (portion of an) array, divides it into partitions, then sorts those
    void quicksort(int[] A, int lo, int hi) {
        if (lo >= 0 && hi >= 0 && lo < hi) {
            int p = partition(A, lo, hi);
            quicksort(A, lo, p); // Note: the pivot is now included
            quicksort(A, p + 1, hi);
        }
    }

    // Divides array into two partitions
    int partition(int[] A, int lo, int hi) {
        // Pivot value
        int pivot = A[ (int) Math.floor((hi - lo)/2) + lo ]; // The value in the middle of the array

        // Left index
        int i = lo - 1;

        // Right index
        int j = hi + 1, t;

        while (true) {
            // Move the left index to the right at least once and while the element at
            // the left index is less than the pivot
            do i = i + 1;
            while (A[i] < pivot);

            // Move the right index to the left at least once and while the element at
            // the right index is greater than the pivot
            do j = j - 1;
            while (A[j] > pivot);

            // If the indices crossed, return
            if (i >= j) return j;

            // Swap the elements at the left and right indices
            t = A[i];
            A[i] = A[j];
            A[j] = t;
        }
    }
}
```